# clang-format adds newline before typedef name when struct defined with macro __PACKED_STRUCT

Tags: c, code-formatting, clang-format

I am running clang-format on my C code which includes a large number of packed structs like this.  It keeps moving the typedef name onto a new line following the closing brace.  Is there a way I can update my .clang-format file to fix this?

This is the input (I want it to be unchanged)

```
typedef __PACKED_STRUCT nv_iis_VersionInfo_s
{
    uint8_t versionMajor;
    uint8_t versionMinor;
    uint8_t versionRevision;
} nv_iis_VersionInfo_t;
```

clang-format produces this output:

```
typedef __PACKED_STRUCT nv_iis_VersionInfo_s
{
    uint8_t versionMajor;
    uint8_t versionMinor;
    uint8_t versionRevision;
}
nv_iis_VersionInfo_t;
```

The problem is related to the __PACKED_STRUCT macro.  If this was a regular struct like this it works as expected:

```
typedef struct nv_iis_VersionInfo_s
{
    uint8_t versionMajor;
    uint8_t versionMinor;
    uint8_t versionRevision;
} nv_iis_VersionInfo_t;
```

Comment: I guess the formatting problem might be triggered by the absence of the keyword ```struct``` in the packed version, which causes the enforcement of the rules related to code blocks instead.

Comment: You can try and wrap the code you don't want to format between ```// clang-format off``` (or ```/* clang-format off */```) and ```// clang-format on``` (or ```/* clang-format on */```), but I'd honestly prefer the output of clang-format. :)

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Clang-17, I believe you might be able to resolve this with the [`Macros` option](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html#macros):

```yaml
Macros:
  - PACKED_STRUCT=struct __attribute__((packed))
```